# The method 'updatePhoneNumberCredential' isn't defined for the type 'User' (firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I recently updated firebase auth to the latest version. Since then I have the following problem:

The method 'updatePhoneNumberCredential' isn't defined for the type 'User'.

I am very grateful for any help!

This is my code:

```
                        if (widget.updateNumber) {
                        User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                        user
                            .updatePhoneNumberCredential(_phoneAuth)
                            .then((_) => updateNumber())
                            .catchError(
                          (e) {
                            CustomSnackBar.snackBar(
                                "Enter the Code sent to your Phone Number",
                                _scaffoldKey);
                          },
                        );
                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is called `updatePhoneNumber()`, you need to pass to it a variable of type `PhoneAuthCredential`:

Check the declaration here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/user.dart#L339

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)